# scroll to bottom of a div having dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed height div with dynamic content. I want auto scroll to the bottom when some content is added to the div.

I found `scrollTop = scrollHeight` solution on SO but it is not working in my condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = '<p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p>'
  
  $("#content").html(text);
  $("#content").scrollTop($('#content').scrollHeight)
})
```

```css
#content{
  max-height:250px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$("#content").scrollTop($('#content').scrollHeight)
```

to

```
$("#content").scrollTop($('#content')[0].scrollHeight)
```

Comment: `.height()` will output the height of the container (in this case 250px because of the `max-height: 250px`. This won't help to get the "scrollable height"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

Here is demo: https://output.jsbin.com/vobomafehi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var text = '<p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p><p>some text</p>'
      $("#content").html(text);
      $("#content").scrollTop($('#content')[0].scrollHeight);
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #content{
      max-height:250px;
      overflow-y:auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$('#content').scrollHeight` is undefined. You have to access it like this:
`$('#content')[0].scrollHeight`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sr8fnv4k/

Why?
Because some properties are not transferred to jQuery. When this is the case, you need to access the original HTML-Tag attributes.